# Find the string containing the closest time to a given datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

I have a dataframe with one column containing a time

```
myDf=pd.DataFrame(data=['12:53 AM ','1:53 AM '])
```

and so on.
I could parse the string using the following

```
myDf['LOCALTIME']=myDf[name_columns_with_time].apply(lambda tt:pd.to_datetime(tt, format='%I:%M %p')).dt.time
```

to get

```
myDf['LOCALTIME']
Out[287]: 
0     00:53:00
1     01:53:00
2     02:53:00
```

However, this is column is a `dobject` as dtype.

Now I have a datetime:

```
just_a_datetime = datetime.datetime(year=2016, month=8, day=7,hour=1,minute=45,second=1)
```

and I need to identify which row of `myDF` is the closest to the `just_a_datetime`.
In this example: the desired result is `1`.
I wanted to do like:

```
myDf['LOCALTIME'].dt-datetime_of_interest.time()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using `np.searchsorted`

```
np.searchsorted(df.LOCALTIME.dt.time.values, pd.to_datetime(just_a_datetime).time())
Out[323]: 1
```

Comment: I still get raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike "

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: when using your solution

Comment: @ErroriSalvo do you nitice `pd.to_datetime(just_a_datetime).time()` and `df.LOCALTIME.dt.time.values`

Comment: pd.to_datetime(datetime_of_interest).time() works correctly

Comment: However,     weather_df.LOCALTIME.dt.time.values returns AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: even though it was generated with pd.to_datetime

Comment: @ErroriSalvo `weather_df.LOCALTIME=pd.to_datetime(weather_df.LOCALTIME)`, then doing above calculation

Comment: It is getting weird: if I do that  I get TypeError: <type 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: In the end I have solved. For some reasons my .apply() was not working